# How can I plot (and compare) the efficiency in executing 2 functions?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have two functions as follows,

```
Multifactorial[n_, k_] := Abs[Apply[Times, Range[-n, -1, k]]]
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++, Print[N[Sum[1/Multifactorial[n, i], {n, 0, 150}], 20]]]
```

and

```
ClosedFormRMFC[n_] := 1 + 1/n Exp[1/n] Sum[n^(k/n) Gamma[k/n, 0, 1/n], {k, n}]
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++, Print[N[ClosedFormRMFC[i], 20]]]
```

Both the functions have an identical output, they both output 10 numerical constants with a 20 decimal accuracy.

I am not sure how to compare the efficiency in executing both these functions.

The first function is an infinite series and as such needs arbitrarily large partial sums to get higher accuracy. While the second gives a closed form formula that just needs to be converted to a numerical form.

For higher values of accuracy I assume the second function must be computationally more efficient.

My question is how can I test this in Mathematica?
How do I determine which is more efficient asymptotically?
Is there some way to plot a graph showing the time taken in executing both functions for various levels of accuracy (in output)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do the following should work.

We start by

```
Multifactorial[n_, k_] := Abs[Apply[Times, Range[-n, -1, k]]]
```

Then we define a function that does the computation but does not show any output. This function also computes the absolute time that mathematica needs. This is done as follows

```
test1[xx_] := (For[i = 1, i < xx, i++, 
     Print[N[Sum[1/Multifactorial[n, i], {n, 0, 150}], 20]] // 
      Inactive] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
```

To make a long story short, we do the same for the other function you provided

```
ClosedFormRMFC[n_] := 
 1 + 1/n Exp[1/n] Sum[n^(k/n) Gamma[k/n, 0, 1/n], {k, n}]

test2[xx_] := (For[i = 1, i < xx, i++, 
     Print[N[ClosedFormRMFC[i], 20]] // Inactive] // 
    AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
```

And now it is relatively straightforward. We can create two lists that enumerate how many points we are taking each time and how much time each function needs. At the very end, `ListPlot` is our friend

```
list1 = ListPlot[Table[{xx, test1[xx]}, {xx, 1, 25}], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
   AxesLabel -> {"points", "time in sec"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
list2 = ListPlot[Table[{xx, test2[xx]}, {xx, 1, 25}], 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
   AxesLabel -> {"points", "time in sec"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
```

And we gather everything

```
Show[list1, list2]
```

[image]

If this is not what you were looking for, please leave a comment and I will either modify this or delete altogeher.

Comment: Thanks this is very nice solution indeed. You can even switch around the test variable xx to be in place of decimal accuracy, I'll try playing around a little with this.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: +1 Although slower, `RepeatedTiming` gives more stable results.

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for the comment. I was not aware of the RepeatedTiming command. Is it significantly slower compared to AbsoluteTiming?

Comment: "RepeatedTiming always evaluates expr at least four times. It gives a trimmed mean of the timings obtained, discarding lower and upper quartiles."

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for the clarification. Would you like to write an answer demonstrating the use of RepeatedTiming for completeness?

Comment: No, I don't think that it is necessary. It would literally just replace `AbsoluteTiming` with `RepeatedTiming`